# Embedded Jetty 9 + OpenJdk jdk8u212-b03 + SSL using certifiacte not working

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, embedded-jetty

As a sanity check, I created a composite cert file with the following certificates: MyCert, IntermediateCert, RootCert, PrivateKey.  I created a simple Python webserver employing this composite cert file and used curl to verify that HTTPS works.

But I want to run Jetty, not Python webserver. So...

I created a keystore as follows:

```
keytool -importcert -file ./MyCert.pem -keystore keystore -alias ducc-master.abc.com
keytool -importcert -file ./IntermediateCert.pem -keystore keystore -alias caintermediate
keytool -importcert -file ./RootCert.pem -keystore keystore -alias caroot
```

I code my embedded Jetty webserver thus:

```
...
HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
http_config.setSecurePort(portHttps);
HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector(server,
new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,"http/1.1"),
new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
https.setPort(portHttps);
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(pw); 
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystore);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(pw);    
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(keystore);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(pw);
sslContextFactory.setCertAlias("ducc-master-1.abc.com");
sslContextFactory.setRenegotiationAllowed(true);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { https });
server.addConnector(https);
server.start();
server.join();
```

When I try to visit the webserver, no joy.

```
curl -k https://localhost:57081
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

On the webserver console I see:

> 2019-08-07 09:36:50.963:DBUG:oejs.HttpConnection:qtp662948858-27: 
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:802)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)    at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:653)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:322)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$2.000000001C7E7860.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813) Caused by: 
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:306)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1127)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:814)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:221)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:739)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:747)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:322)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$2.000000001C7E7860.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)

So I must be building my keystore incorrectly, or configuring my embedded webserver incorrectly?

Comment: If you use `curl --trace trace.log --verbose --tlsv1.2 --insecure https://localhost:57081` what does the handshake look like? (up to the point where the GET request occurs)

Comment: Your aliases don't match.  The command line has a different alias then what your code declares.